# Elasticsearch nested exclude data by multiply conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some example data like these

```
{
  list:[{id:1,amount:0},{id:2,amount:1},{id:1,amount:1}]
},
{
   list:[{id:1,amount:0},{id:2,amount:1},{id:1,amount:0}]
}
```

I would like to exclude all the data meet the condition like `id=1` and `amount=0`,so I will get

```
{
 list:[{id:1,amount:0},{id:2,amount:1},{id:1,amount:1}]
}
```

because `{id:1,amount:1}`does not meet the condition,so the first data will be retained, my idea is like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "list",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "list.id": {
                        "value": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "list.amount": {
                        "value": 0
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but it does not work out,does anyone has any ideas?

Comment: so your expected search result will be `{id:2,amount:1},{id:1,amount:1}` ?

Comment: can you share your mapping and query results.